# Ajuda com uma tabela associativa de amigos

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, codeigniter

Eu tenho uma tabela de amigos, que tem a seguinte composição:

> id_amigos (id da relação)
>
> id_usuario_de (id do usuário que enviou a solicitação de amizade)
>
> id_usuario_para (id do usuário que recebeu a solicitação de amizade)
>
> id_status (se o usuário que recebeu a solicitação aceitou ou não)

Todo o sistema de enviar/aceitar está pronto, agora quero fazer com que seja carregada uma lista dos amigos do usuário logado, na qual eu pensei na seguinte lógica (utilizando a mesma tabela).

**Se**: o `id_usuario_de` for igual ao `id_usuario` logado, traga o `id_usuario_para` (que será um amigo do usuário logado)

**Senão**: se o `id_usuario_para` for igual ao `id_usuario` logado, traga o `id_usuario_de` (que também será um amigo do usuário logado, porém foi ele que enviou a solicitação).

Preciso trazer apenas o `id_usuario` do amigo do usuário logado, mas não consigo/não faço ideia de como fazer isso com MySQL.

Desde já agradeço a ajuda e peço desculpas se a pergunta ficou muito confusa.

### edit

Eu consegui o resultado esperado com a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT usuario.id_usuario, usuario.nome_completo, caminho,  usuario.descricao FROM usuario, foto_usuario 
WHERE (usuario.id_usuario 
IN (SELECT id_usuario2 FROM amigos WHERE id_usuario1 = $usuario AND  id_status = 8) 
OR usuario.id_usuario 
IN (SELECT id_usuario1 FROM amigos WHERE id_usuario2 = $usuario AND id_status = 8)) 
AND usuario.id_usuario != $usuario AND usuario.id_usuario = foto_usuario.id_usuario
```

Porém ela ficou bem grande, estive pensando se não tem uma maneira mais "fácil" de fazer ela...

PS: 
- id_usuario1 = id_usuario_de, id_usuario2 = id_usuario_para
- Na consulta eu pego alguns dados extras como foto e descrição
- O `id_status = 8` é o id que sinaliza que a relação foi aceita, ou seja, o `id_usuario_para` aceitou o pedido de amizade

Comment: Não tem nenhum ponto de partida em relação à consulta MySQL? Pode colocar isso na sua questão?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode utilizar a seguinte consulta, para trazer todos os usuários que enviaram convites para o usuário logado.

```
SELECT id_usuario, usuario.nome, usuario.ultimo_nome FROM usuario 
INNER JOIN amigos ON amigos.id_usuario_de = usuario.id 
WHERE amigos.id_usuario_para = <id_do_usuario_logado>
```

Essa consulta irá resultar em todos os usuários que enviarem convites ao usuário logado.

Comment: Sim, porem so traz os usuarios que mandaram solicitação ao usuario logado, e não todos os amigos do usuario logado, mas, a logica da consulta me ajudou a entender como funciona para consultar as duas colunas da tabelas simultaneamente

Answer (score 0):

Boa tarde!
No caso você pode cruzar as duas tabelas.

Acredito que você tenha duas tabelas tb_usuario, tb_usuario_solicitacao (apenas exemplo).
Faça o Seguinte.

```
SELECT * FROM tb_usuario AS usuario
JOIN tb_usuario_solicitacao AS solicitacao ON solicitacao.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
WHERE solicitacao.id_usuario_para = <id_user>
```

Irá obter uma lista de todos os usuarios que fizeram a solicitacao

para melhorar ainda pode puxar apenas os amigos que ele aceitou:

```
SELECT * FROM tb_usuario AS usuario
JOIN tb_usuario_solicitacao AS solicitacao ON solicitacao.id_usuario = usuario.id_usuario
WHERE solicitacao.id_usuario_para = <id_user> AND solicitacao.id_status = 1
```

Comment: No seu exemplo aconteceu o mesmo da resposta acima, ele retorna apenas quando o id_usuario logado esta gravado no id_usuario_para, mas me ajudou bastante na questão, obrigado